# Collision in java and libgdx in making an android game

Tags: java, libgdx

i've already followed this steps here - [Sprite not moving properly. libgdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467939/sprite-not-moving-properly-libgdx)

i have a hero, a simple crate and the map. i want to attach a collision on the crate so that when the hero collides with the crate it won't pass through. how can i do that using the codes from the link?

Answer (score 0):

To get this thing done , i will advice you to use , Box2D instead of simple collision check ,via bounds/position.  Plus it will look more realistic . 
 Create 2 bodies , one for player(Dynamic Body) and one for crate(Static Body).In that case You will not need to check collision  to make sure player won't pass through crate.